# Firebase v3 Query by Grandchild

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When registering new email/password type users,  I need to make user that the `displayName` that they enter does not already exist in my Realtime Database before calling `.createUserWithEmailAndPassword`.  So I need a query.  I need to get a list of all `displayName`'s in my `users` branch.  I am confused as to how to gather this for each `user` which is denoted by each users auth.uid.

What would the retrieval look like?  I am thinking something like:

`firebase.database().ref('users/' + allUserIds).equalTo('Joe');`

but I know that `allUserIds` is not valid.  Can someone help me with this?

```
{
  "users" : {
    "6mJb9vtpbDelyyjirKEf6sSEj8h1" : {
      "name" : "asdfs@asdf.com",
      "provider" : "password",
      "displayName" : "Joe"
    },
    "T7D7qEOPPHXjKSzglKheGJDQNkE3" : {
      "name" : "gfdsdf@hlkjh.com",
      "provider" : "password",
      "displayName" : "Jane"
    },
    "kTG9R0V4aXYsogQfgF633KFYtzV2" : {
      "name" : "Andre3000",
      "provider" : "google.com",
      "displayName" : "Andre"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use Firebase queries for that:

```
var users = firebase.database().ref('users');
var joes = users.orderByChild('displayName').equalTo('Joe');
joes.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log('A Joe does '+(snapshot.exists()?'':'not ')+' exist')
});
```

Don't forget to define an index on `users`:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": "displayName"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You run the query on the collection, but order/filter on a property of the individual items. That's indeed always a bit confusing. Which remind me, don't forget to put an `.indexOn` on the right level. I've added an example.

Comment: There are no `return` statements in my code, so I'm not sure what you mean. If you're having trouble getting it to work, can you set up a jsfiddle/jsbin that reproduces that problem?

Comment: This particular effort is unnecessary.  `.updateProfile` stores the `displayName` and `photoURL` properties in the Firebase Auth system. Therefore, there is no need to set/get this stuff under a users node in your Realtime Database.

Comment: @RonRoyston Firebase Authentication indeed keeps the display name for each user. But it doesn't (currently) have an API to get a list of users. Since many apps need that functionality, developers often end up keeping a list of users/names in the database.

Comment: Understood.  I'm just saying there's no need to store displayName or photoURL in your Realtime Database.  Password based auth does not ask for these attributes/properties nor does it require it.  Intuition told me this stuff was read from oAuth providers and Password based auth needed special handling.  It doesn't.  The Auth system can store this stuff for you and will set all this to `localstorage` for your users.  Maybe it's just me but I didn't realize this until I found that updateProfile method with isn't really documented other than showing up in an index of methods.

Comment: Here you go, Frank: All rolled into one - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/rOe7BB_FcTc

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd share my somewhat fleshed out solution.  Call with `myApp.displayNameExists('Joe')`.

```
var myApp = (function() {
    var pub = {};
    pub.displayNameExists = function(name) {
            var users = firebase.database().ref('users');
            var duplicate = users.orderByChild('displayName').equalTo(name);
            duplicate.once('value').then(function(snap) {
                if (snap.val()) {
                    console.log('found. ask for new display name');
                } else {
                    console.log('name unique.  ok to write this user to db');
                }
            }, function(error) {
                // The Promise was rejected.
                console.error(error);
            });
        }
        //API
    return pub;
}());
```