# Retrieve nested data from firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I've a Firebase database, and the data looks like this:

[Firebase Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KZIK.png)

I want to retrieve data, where `food` Object comes in the data along with theme.

I've tried, this:

```
return this.af.database.object(`themes/${id}`)
          .map((items) => {
            return items.menu.map(food => {
              return this.af.database.object(`foods/${food}`);
            });
            // return items;
          })
          .concatAll()
          .subscribe((d) => console.log(d));
```

This way, I'm getting this in console.

`FirebaseObjectObservable {_isScalar: false, _ref: W}`

Is what I need, achievable?

Also, is this the right way, of saving and retrieving data?

I'm new to rxjs and angular2. Any lead will help.

Thanks,

Comment: [Firebase v3 Query by Grandchild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38515142/firebase-v3-query-by-grandchild)