# Query data by value of deep child

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a data structure like this:

```
groups
  -KOrPKM2QUzuMnMlHfJu
    name: "Testgroup 1"
    members
      0: 123456789
      1: 987654321

  -KOrPKM2QUzuMnMFGfXa
    name: "Testgroup 2"
    members
      0: 123456789
```

The number of members is not defined.
How can I get every group where one of the members is `123456789`?

This question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38515142/firebase-v3-query-by-grandchild) because in the other one the key of the value to check is actually known.

Comment: you need to change your structure in members ..

Answer (score 0):

The unique ID is generated when `push` is used, to retrieve the values under that node, you can use `child_added`.

```
firebase.database().ref('groups').on('child_added', snap => {
  firebase.database().ref('groups/'+snap.key+'/members').on('child_added', childSnapshot => {
    if(childSnapshot.val() == '123456789') {
      console.log('123456789 found in ' + snap.val().name);
    }
  });
});
```

The above code adds a `child_added` listener to `groups` so the moment it finds an existing child under `groups` or when a new child is added, it will trigger `child_added`, now `snap.key` contains what you want, the unique generated ID, to compare the value stored in `members`, another `child_added` listener is set on `members` which returns all the value stored under 0, 1...

Now `childSnapshot.val()` contains the value you want to compare, a simple IF statement is enough and if a match is found, you just print the group name with `snap.val().name`;

Answer (score 0):

I created NSObject class and called it FBNSArrayDB, inside it I created the firebase ID's in your case it will be:

```
   var name: NSString?
    var members: NSString?
    var 0: NSString?
var 1: NSString?
```

then do this in your UIViewController

```
var fbarray = [FBNSArrayDB]()//at the top
```

inside func

```
 let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(uid!)// I assume you are saving this under uid nod!



    ref.child("groups").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
            let xy = FBNSArrayDB()
            xy.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary)

            guard let SomeV = xy.0

                    else {
                        print ("NA")
                        return
                }

                if SomeV == "123456789"
{
self.fbarray.append(xy) //this way you can use the array values outside the Func

print (xy.name)
print (xy.0)
print (xy.1)
print (snapshot.key) // if you want to get the AutoID 



 }


        }
        }, withCancelBlock: nil)
```

Comment: This won't work because the number of members under the `members` key is infinite. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: can you tell me how did you build the database under childByAutoId, i would like to try something

Comment: You could add a group like this: `self.ref.child("groups").childByAutoId().setValue(["name": "Testgroup1",  "members": [123456789]])`