# dataSnapshot.key() doesn't works in new version firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am trying to retrieving data from database into a `ListView`. I wanna store the id as `dataSnapshot.key()`

But it seems like new version of firebase doesn't support this function any more. When I am using it it keeping appears error.

Any one know what kind of variable can I use to instead it?

[image]

Comment: Can you post some code? Are you doing something like this: `database.ref('something').on('value', snap => { console.log(snap.key); });` This works but like I said you need to post some code.

Comment: Hi Chinmay, thank you for your reply, this method you're mentioning above does works in my code!

Comment: Btw do you know how to get child's id of firebase database? As the picture I just uploaded, there are only some random generated code for it. I don't know how to insert data under it since I don't know how to get the name. Thank you a lot

Comment: I recently posted an answer on this exact topic, you can find it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38887898/4152581).

Comment: Version 2.x of the Firebase SDK had a `DataSnapshot.key()` function. In version 3.x this changed to a read-only property, so `DataSnapshot.key`. This and many more (small) changes are covered in the [migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web#get_a_database_reference_numbered).